# How do you prove this asymptotic relations between $n!$ and $\frac1en+\frac1{2e}\ln(2 \pi n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\varepsilon(n):=\frac1en+\frac1{2e}\ln(2 \pi n)$. Toying around in Wolfram, I found the following results:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\varepsilon(n)^n}{n!}=1 \tag{1}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\varepsilon(n)-\sqrt[n]{n!}=0 \tag{2}$$

Is this correct? How could one prove it? Are there any more meaningful relations between $\varepsilon(n)$ and $n!$ ?

Comment: @MichalZalapa Check Stirling's formula.

Comment: @PierreCarre It doesn't seem equivalent  with what I'm asking about

Comment: It does... Since $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n $, you can make the replacement in the limit to get rid of the factorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
& \left( {\frac{1}{e}n + \frac{1}{{2e}}\log (2\pi n)} \right)^n = \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}\log \sqrt {2\pi n} } \right)^n 
\\ &
 = \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}\log \sqrt {2\pi n} } \right)} \right) \\& = \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \exp \left( {n\left( {\frac{1}{n}\log \sqrt {2\pi n}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)} \right)
\\ &
 = \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} \exp \left( {\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right)} \right) = \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right)} \right).
\end{align*}
Thus, (1) follows from Stirling's formula. For (2), we have by Stirling's formula,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{{n!}} & = \frac{n}{e}\sqrt[n]{{\sqrt {2\pi n} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)}}
\\ &
 = \frac{n}{e}\sqrt[{2n}]{{2\pi n}}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right) = \frac{n}{e}\exp \left( {\frac{1}{{2n}}\log (2\pi n)} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)
\\ &
 = \frac{n}{e}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}}\log (2\pi n) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)
\\ &
 = \frac{n}{e} + \frac{1}{{2e}}\log (2\pi n) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right).
\end{align*}